# Angular 2 cant make models object's json constant

Tags: angular, typescript

Issue :
Constant variable with value as Array of models is getting change without any direct change into that variable.

**My model is :**

```
export class Section {

    sectionId : string;
    sectionLabel : string;
    sectionIcon : string;
    sectionComponents : Array<SectionComponent>; 
}
```

Now I have to declare one default array variable of this model which must be constant at everywhere in project

**Appropriate json for this model is :**

```
SECTIONS_CONST: Section[] = [ 

          {
            sectionId: 'testId',
            sectionLabel: 'testLabel',
            sectionIcon : 'testIcon',
            sectionComponents : [
                      {
                        sectionComponentId : 'testSectionComponentId',
                        label : 'test label',
                        inputModels : [
                           {
                             inputName : 'testName',
                             model : ''
                           }
                          ],
                        componentBasedData : null,
                        selectedQuerys : []
                      }
                ]
          }
]
```

**Note** : This array is properly working in my code, but the only problem is, in this array no any values have to change any how.

**I tried many ways as below :**

> - Made this variable private in class and by getter method returns this variable's value
> - Export this variable as constant
> - Tried Object.assign({}, yourObject);
> - Tried Object.freeze()
> - Tried _.cloneDeep()

And much more things I tried.

Still trying with different solutions but cant getting anything working.

Comment: Are you saying that `SECTIONS_CONST` is changing somehow and you don't want it to change?

Comment: Have you tried `Immutable.js` library?

Comment: Yes @Huangism. I dont want to change this variable's value.

Comment: Then where are you using this var? It must be changing because it is used somewhere. Also can't you declare it as a `const` ?

Comment: Ye @Huangism. I tried many ways as below :
Made this variable private in class and by getter method returns this variable's value
Export this variable as constant,
Tried Object.assign({}, yourObject); ,
Tried Object.freeze() ,
Tried _.cloneDeep()

Comment: @vishal rana Did my answer help at all?

Comment: @Frank Modica, I appreciate for your help and I also tried your suggested way. But its not working in my case as I am assigning this variable's value to another variable to use it. But with your solution Its not allowing me to add/remove anything from the variable in which I am assigning this value.

Comment: At finally I did my solution as I took json file for my json and read it from that file whenever I need initial json. That is good and proper solution for my case because my json can be vary any time whenever I need to change.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into `ReadonlyArray` combined with `const`?

```
const SECTIONS_CONST: ReadonlyArray<Section> = ...
```

With `ReadonlyArray` you won't be able to add or change items:

```
// Not allowed
SECTIONS_CONST.push( ... );
SECTIONS_CONST[0] = ...
```

And `const` prevents reassignment:

```
// Not allowed
SECTIONS_CONST = [];
```

However you can still change a property on an existing item:

```
SECTIONS_CONST[0].sectionId = null;
```

So you may want to make the properties of `Section` readonly too:

```
export class Section {
    readonly sectionId : string;
    // etc
}

// Not allowed
SECTIONS_CONST[0].sectionId = null;
```